# Custom Rails Dashboard, how to optimize data retrieval to display in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model, controller, dashboard

I am making a custom dashboard for a school application that requires me to calculate some KPIs, the way am doing it right now is calling several class methods from the Opportunity class in the dashboard/index action from the controller, and storing each method result in a variable that is going to be used in a tile. So each variable is a different tile of the dashboard.

The methods belong to the Opportunity class shown below:

```
class Opportunity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :opportunity_status
  has_many   :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :opportunity_status_logs, dependent: :destroy

  before_create :create_status_log
  after_update  :create_status_log, if: :opportunity_status_id_changed?

  validates :name, :description, :revenue, :opportunity_status_id, :closing_date, presence: true
  validates :name, :description, format: { with: /\A[[:alpha:]a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ#()\-.,\s]+\z/ }
  validates :revenue, numericality: true
  validates :closing_date, inclusion: { in: (Time.zone.today..Time.zone.today+5.years) }


  def create_status_log
    OpportunityStatusLog.create(opportunity_id: self.id, opportunity_status_id: self.opportunity_status_id)
  end

  def status_updated_by(user)
    @status_log = self.opportunity_status_logs.last
    @status_log.user_id = user.id
    @status_log.save!
  end

  def self.actives
    self.where.not(opportunity_status_id: [11,12])
  end

  def self.won
    self.where(opportunity_status_id: 11)
  end

  def self.lost
    self.where(opportunity_status_id: 12)
  end

  def self.average_revenue
    self.won.average(:revenue)
  end

  def self.minimum_revenue
    self.won.minimum(:revenue)
  end

  def self.maximum_revenue
    self.won.maximum(:revenue)
  end

  def self.filter_by_status(status_id)
    self.where(opportunity_status: status_id)
  end

  def self.relative_percentage(item_amount, total)
    item_amount * 100 / total
  end

  def self.conversion_rate
    self.won.count / self.all.count.to_f * 100
  end

  def self.potential_revenue
    self.actives.sum(:revenue)
  end
end
```

and this is the way the controller is structured:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @opportunities = Opportunity.includes(:opportunity_status).all
    @actives = Opportunity.actives.count
    @won = Opportunity.won.count
    @lost = Opportunity.lost.count
    @average_revenue = Opportunity.average_revenue
    @minimum_revenue = Opportunity.minimum_revenue
    @maximum_revenue = Opportunity.maximum_revenue 
    @in_appreciation = Opportunity.filter_by_status(6).count
    @in_value_proposition = Opportunity.filter_by_status(7).count
    @in_management_analysis = Opportunity.filter_by_status(8).count
    @in_proposal = Opportunity.filter_by_status(9).count
    @in_review = Opportunity.filter_by_status(10).count
    @app_perc = Opportunity.relative_percentage(@in_appreciation, @opportunities.count)
    @vp_perc = Opportunity.relative_percentage(@in_value_proposition, @opportunities.count)
    @ma_perc = Opportunity.relative_percentage(@in_management_analysis, @opportunities.count)
    @pp_perc = Opportunity.relative_percentage(@in_proposal, @opportunities.count)
    @rw_perc = Opportunity.relative_percentage(@in_review, @opportunities.count)
    @conversion_rate = '%.2f' % [Opportunity.conversion_rate]
    @potential_revenue = Opportunity.potential_revenue
  end
end
```

Even though it works as expected, it looks like the controller is a bit too fat and I feel that with the current approach if the app scales it will be very slow due to the amount of queries that are being done. So, is there a way to refactor this in order to optimize the data retrieval and the displaying of the KPIs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try implementing [Facade Pattern in Rails](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/models/facade_pattern.html). It will make your controller skinny but on the query part you will still be needing to make those queries, there is no way to skip that.

You can try to optimize db by adding index and creating sql views in future when you get performance lag, at this time it will be like premature optimization

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for the quick response and the very helpful resource, i will implement it as soon as i get home, definitely what i was talking about. I though that it was kind of impossible to avoid the amount of queries but with this new approach it surely will look a lot cleaner and better for testing.

Comment: Glad to know it helped :)